# How to load different content based upon URL used to visit site i CodeIgniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm sure I'm not the first person who has thought about this but I haven't had any luck forming that proper search query in google to find the info. Here's what I'm wanting to do:

I have a CodeIgniter based site. I'm going to store basic content into tables in the db. I'm thinking that I would have the domain names stored in table to and use the unique id of the table row as the method of querying the appropriate content from the db for the rest of the views. For example. MyDomain.com is #1 in the row followed by YourDomain.com. If the visitor arrived at the site by typing YourDomain.com then somehow CI would "see" that and then query the content for that domain from the db.

Does this make sense? Has anyone else tried it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done it myself, but I did some searching for "codeigniter multi site" and found some useful links, [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/175084/) being one of them that seemed to step you through the process.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for and filled in the missing piece. I was thinking that was the way but wasn't sure and that post confirmed my suspicions. I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general there is an HTTP_HOST header (or similar header) that identifies the host in the user's request. You can look that header up and then use that to index into your database to extract the right content.